# Hi, how to change the value in the dependent drop down list immediately after copying the drop down to another cell in excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have created a dependent dynamic drop-down list based on another drop-down. Please check the below image. However, when I am copying the drop-down to another cell, Although the drop-down list is getting updated based on the dynamic reference, **the value that was selected earlier was not changing**.

For example, as shown in the below image. I have copied the drop-down that has a value of 4.09 to another cell. As you can see although the drop-down list got updated the value 4.09 is not changing. I ideally expect it to change as 4.09 is not a part of this dropdown list values. could anyone help me how can I  achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is automatic calculation selected for the sheet?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by automatic but it is dynamic. The Values in the drop-down will change based on the cell value under the Price Matrix in the image (blue colored line).

Answer (score 0):

See my screenshots below - here are two options you can consider (once you've pasted the value corresponding to 4.09 into a cell, it will remain that way until it's changed by some mechanism other than validation lists - if I've interpreted/understood your Q properly - these lists are only designed to capture an input not change other cells)..

**Option 1:**

Use develeper tab 'combo box' option:

[image: Combo-box menu item (Developer tab in main Ribbon)]

*I've inserted this combo-box so that it aligns with cell D2 (hold 'alt' when dragging edges with mouse to align pefectly with neighbouring cell adjacencies).*

[image: Option 1 set up]

Notice the two cells in F3:G3 - the former corresponds to your validation-list selection (which is what I understand you really want to achieve, the second is a simple lookupp to bring back the valee itself

- *Input range*: `B3:B7`
- *Linked cell*: `G3`

[image: Format Control combo-box configuration]

*Customise according to your specific needs/set-up noting my example is purely demonstrative.*

Now whenever I make a new selection (e.g. light build or q

---

**Option 2** - use worksheet_change VB code:

shorcut keys: (alt + F11 to open VB; CTRL + R to view Project Explorer if (default) view not already showing; double click sheet in question (here Sheet1) to open VB editor pane, insert following code:

[image: VB code in Module 1 of sheet in question]

---